# How do I fix no mic input in pipewire?

Tags: audio, pipewire

I have bought myself a Sound BlasterX G6 and a pair of Beyerdynamic MMX 300 but I'm struggling with getting the microphone to register any sound. I'm using Fedora 35 so `alsamixer` does not work anymore, either.

Is there a way to edit the settings, either in files or, by CLI/GUI?

Under is a screenshot of the sound controls in the GNOME Settings.
[image: GNOME Settings]

**EDIT:** it started working by itself. Don't know why.

Comment: IF you're using kernel 5.17.5 and it still doesn't work please report to https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/issues

Comment: Yes, I'm using kernel 5.17.5 - is this a know issue or something? EDIT: I reported the bug.

Comment: You're expected to follow up, please. A developer asked you a question.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I forgot to check the issue. Thanks for reminding me. It just started *magically* working, so I closed the issue.

Comment: LOL, ok, good luck :-)

Comment: I had a similar issue, although I'm on PopOS 22.04 (kernal 5.17.5) which is running pipewire. Restarting the OS did nothing, but I found that running `systemctl --user restart pipewire` afterwards tended to sort things out in the short-term.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Are you using the G6 as well?